# Using XPC to parallelize Cocoa WebView rendering

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, ipc, nsxpcconnection

My Cocoa app needs to simultaneously render many batches of generated web pages. Since WebKit WebView rendering is restricted to the main thread, I can't use GCD to do this within the application's process, so I'm looking at using some sort of inter-process solution.

`NSXPCConnection` is the obvious choice, since it plays nice with the sandbox and transparently proxies all the Core Foundation types I'll need to work with. However, it appears to only ever create a single process per service, which just moves my main-thread-restriction into a different process and doesn't let me parallelize multiple rendering requests. Is there any way to convince the XPC system to fork multiple processes for the same service, possibly using the C API (`xpc_connection_create`, etc.)?

At this point I'm considering make a dozen identical `XPCServices` bundles with different names and connecting to whichever ones are idle for a particular batch of parallel render requests, but that just seems silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I opened a technical support issue with Apple, and they responded that "there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the currently shipping system configurations", so I guess it can't be done.

I wound up creating 20 identical XPC services and launching `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processorCount]` instances and I manually manage communicating with them. It actually works pretty well, and I'm able to max out all the processors with rendering tasks.

Comment: I'm using a similar set up to the one you've described here for an application I'm working on. However, my service is rather unreliable and seems to crash quite frequently with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in random spots. It almost looks like the WebView isn't happy. My XPC service is nothing more than the basic service wrapper with a WebView created on the main thread that loads a URL and reports back when finished. Did you have to do anything "special" in your service to make WebView happy? I changed the RunLoopType to NSRunLoop and force the main thread where appropriate. Anything else?